# How should an ERD for a blog website look?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, erd

I'm trying to think about how to structure a database for a blog website.  Here are my thoughts so far:

User:

- Username PK
- Password
- Privilege Level (to be handled with PHP on webpage)

Posts

- Post ID PK
- Username FK
- Title
- Content
- Time posted

Comments

- Comment ID PK
- Post ID FK
- Username FK
- Content
- Time posted

How does this look?

Comment: Accounts? Authentication? IP logging? Flood Control? User Profile? Pages? Templates? Navigation? Categories? Tags? Images? Revision History? Post Metadata?

Comment: I added a Password field to User for accounts.  Most of the other stuff will be on the webpage itself.  This is just a primitive website for a class I'm in.  I'm just trying to get a solid database design so I don't screw it up from the beginning.

Comment: Given the scope of your design it is reasonable. The only issues are 1. When two posts have the same time you do not record an order for them, if you care, which maybe you don't. 2. Observe that there are common aspects of posts & comments, ie one could consider that there is an  entity type that they both are of. Search re database/sql subtyping/subtables. PS [so]'s database is at [data.se].

Comment: PPS A FK is characterized by a list of columns in a table to a list of columns in a table. A candidate key (of which you can pick one as PK) is a set of columns. So it is better to explicitly state these instead of labelling individual columns. Although that is frequently not done textually. Although an ER diagram participation line (FK) shows the 2 tables and it is assumed that it connects *all* of  *same-named* attributes/columns.